# python lmfit program not running

Tags: python, python-3.x, lmfit

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from lmfit.model import load_model


def mysine(x, amp, freq, shift):
    return amp * np.sin(x*freq + shift)



data = np.loadtxt('sinedata.dat')
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]

model = load_model('sinemodel.sav', funcdefs={'mysine': mysine})
params = model.make_params(amp=3, freq=0.52, shift=0)
params['shift'].max = 1
params['shift'].min = -1
params['amp'].min = 0.0

result = model.fit(y, params, x=x)
print(result.fit_report())

plt.plot(x, y, 'bo')
plt.plot(x, result.best_fit, 'r-')
plt.show()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\MUHAMMAD ALI QURESHI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2910, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

File "", line 4, in 
    from lmfit.model import load_model

File "C:\Users\MUHAMMAD ALI QURESHI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lmfit__init__.py", line 39, in 
    from .confidence import conf_interval, conf_interval2d

File "C:\Users\MUHAMMAD ALI QURESHI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lmfit\confidence.py", line 10, in 
    from .minimizer import MinimizerException

File "C:\Users\MUHAMMAD ALI QURESHI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lmfit\minimizer.py", line 34, in 
    import uncertainties

File "C:\Users\MUHAMMAD ALI QURESHI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\uncertainties__init__.py", line 224, in 
    from .core import *

File "C:\Users\MUHAMMAD ALI QURESHI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\uncertainties\core.py", line 2889
    POSITIVE_DECIMAL_UNSIGNED_OR_NON_FINITE = ur'((\d*)(.\d*)?|nan|NAN|inf|INF)'
                                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Please provide a full traceback for the error.  It appears that the import of uncertainties is failing, but there isn't enough here to know why (invalid syntax might suggest a Python version problem).   Try a simple `import uncertainties` and `import uncertainties.core` (like, just type those at the Python prompt) and investigate or report the full traceback.

Comment: i  really dont know whats happening. I also try different program related to lmfit but the same error arises.

Comment: File "<ipython-input-13-6df3e4b517ba>", line 1, in <module>
    import uncertainties

  File "C:\Users\MUHAMMAD ALI QURESHI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\uncertainties\__init__.py", line 224, in <module>
    from .core import *

  File "C:\Users\MUHAMMAD ALI QURESHI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\uncertainties\core.py", line 2889
    POSITIVE_DECIMAL_UNSIGNED_OR_NON_FINITE = ur'((\d*)(\.\d*)?|nan|NAN|inf|INF)'
                                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: i cant figure out what is the actual problem . the uncertainty package or the python version problem.

Comment: i also tried the import lmfit in the Ipython console and the same error exists

Comment: You should edit your question to provide the FULL, unedited traceback IN THE QUESTION.

Comment: What about now ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to re-install `uncertainties`.  It looks like the code you have is using `Python2` syntax.

I believe that `uncertainties` needs to (automatically) use the `2to3 tool` on installation -- it looks like some part of that didn't work for you.

It should work to do:

```
C:\.....\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip.exe install --force-reinstall uncertainties
```

Comment: I downloaded the uncertainties form github and place the file in site-packages. This things usually works for me but in case of lmfit it 's not . If u want me to reinstall the unceretainties kindly send me the link of it.

Comment: First, the problem is with `uncertainties`, not with `lmfit`.  More importantly,  do not confuse `place the file in site-packages` with installing the package -- that explains the problem you are seeing.  Instead, you need to install the package with `pip install uncertainties` as stated in both its own instructions and in the answer above.    It appears that the problems you have had are because you did not follow the installation instructions.  Twice.   Hope this helps demonstrate why it is important to follow the instructions.

Comment: OK. let me install it with the proper protocols.

Comment: USING pip i have just download pip-19.0.3 from this https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py... After this am gone nuts no idea what to do now .. :(

Comment: Well, if you are using anaconda python, you can do `conda install pip` and then `pip install uncertainties`.   Or, you could use `conda` to install `uncertainties`,  as there are several conda channels that have `uncertainties` available, including `conda-forge`.  But your question was about why `lmfit` was not working, not about how to use well-documented `pip` and/or `conda` to install Python packages.   Anyway,  the answer tells you exactly how to run `pip install`.

Comment: thank you . i sort out something and it worked for me :)